# QT отображение данных в таблице

Tags: c++, qt

Я новичок в QT, пишу первый "учебный" проект на нем. Хочу отобразить в таблице список объектов. То есть одна строка это один объект. При этом хочу иметь возможность выделить какую либо строку и удалить её при необходимости. Ячейки таблицы должны только отображать данные (read only), а обрабатываться данные должны в диалоговом окне, в котром будут стоять данные из выделенной строки.

Имеется список объектов класса Person. Person состоит из QString'ов и Integer'ов(данные типа имени, фамилии, возраста итд). В WPF есть такая классная вешь как binding при помощи которой можно легко отображать такие вот списки...

Я так понял, что используя QtTableWidget мне надо будет в цикле пройтись через все элементы списка и в каждую ячейку вручную вписать необходимые данные из объекта типа Person. Но как-то это решение мне не очень нравится. Уж очень много кода получается.

Читая документацию я заметил, что есть некая возможноть создать ViewModel/Model/Template для необходимого мне класса, что собственно было бы очень удобно ибо не пришлось бы тогда каждый раз вписывать данные в ячейки вручную, а можно было бы таблице передать просто объект типа Person и она сама бы разобралась какое свойство этого объекта в какую ячейку вставить. За часы чтения форумов и документаций по QT я так и не понял есть ли такая возможность или нет и если есть то как она работает (туториалов не нашел)?

Теперь вопросы по порядку:

1. Какой QT-Widget лучше всего подходит для отображения списка объектов(точнее свойств этих объектов)?
2. Есть ли возможность создать аналог WPF'ной ViewModel в QT?
3. Если есть такая возможность то можно ли ссылку на туториал или краткое объяснение/пример?

P.S. Простите, что как-то очень сумбурно написано, старался как мог. Если что-то не понятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: Можешь посмотреть вот эту ссылку https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4d6eodhamkavog/VovkaCourse.rar

Comment: Кажется действительно то что надо!!! Большое спасибо, сейчас посмотрю подрбнее.